# Faster save method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, activerecord

I must convert ~ 1.300.000 records on my database.
Do you know a method faster than this?

```
Article.find_each(&:save)
```

Comment: do you need to issue associated callbacks?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to update a single field in a table, you can use `update_all` on your ActiveRecord model.

```
Post.update_all(:published=>true)
# UPDATE "posts" SET "published" = 't'
```

This works with an ActiveRecord scopes as well.

```
Post.where(:published=>true).update_all(:published=>false) 
# SQL (3.3ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "published" = 'f' WHERE "posts"."published" = 't'
```

By using this, you can use conditional statements (such as `where`) to pick out common rows in your table and perform `update_all` on them. This is assuming you want to do some form of attribute updating before saving the record.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the number of records in batch (the default is 1000), this number depends on how much memory you have in your server:

```
Article.find_each(:batch_size => 5000) { |r| r.save }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating, you need to bulk insert with a gem like [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). If you are updating, just use [update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all).